# Can Jetpack viewmodel be instantiated in composable function?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

Android documentation says that composable functions can run in parallel:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#parallel

It means, that any specific composable function can be called on any thread.

Then if we instantiate viewModel as follows:

```
@Composable
fun FooScreen(viewModel: FooViewModel = viewModel()) {
    ...
}
```

It means, that *viewModel()* (androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel) can be called on any thread (in particular, on background thread).

Next, if we dig into what *viewModel()* does, it turns out, that it calls *ViewModelProvider#get*. And *ViewModelProvider#get*, in turn, is marked with *@MainThread* annotation.

Does it mean, that we cannot call *viewModel()* inside composable functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say *can* be multi-threaded. They are currently not multi-threaded - composition always runs on the main thread.

There is an [existing feature request for ViewModels](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237006831) specifically to support multi-threaded creation of ViewModels that says:

> This would be particularly helpful for cases such as with the Lifecycle ViewModel Compose API of viewModel(), which would ensure future compatibility for multi-threaded composition.

Comment: Oh, composition is not multi-threaded right now, it WILL BE multi-threaded. Ok, now it`s clear, thank you.